# Internet Sharing on Mac Behind Proxy

Tags: mac, iphone, internet

I have enabled the internet sharing via Airport on Mac mini successfully. I can connect to the Wifi network from my iPhone but can't browse the internet. The problem might be that the Mac mini uses a proxy to connect to the internet. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

First, try entering the proxy settings for your connection into the iPhone. You can do this by going into the Settings app > Wifi > *Wifi network name* > Proxy (which is at the bottom). Note, you cannot specify a .pac proxy file like this on the iPhone.

Unfortunately, this may not work. I had the exact same problem for me, and although it would work fine with my DSi, for some reason, my iPod touch hated the ad-hoc connection.

Comment: This is the correct by-the-book advice. I would be very interesting in diagnosing the failure. You would probably want to start with netstat output.